# QT dll in non-qt application

Tags: c++, qt

I have some problems to distribute my QT class (5.7, msvc) to other developer (He uses borland C++ builder). While loading, my dll application can't find `platforms\qwindows.dll`

Can anybody tell me (with examples) how to create dll and use it in other compilers?

This is my way to export some class methods:

```
#include <string>
#include <QString>
#include "dialog.h"
dialog* dlg;

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void DLLInit() {
    int argcc = 0;
    new QApplication(argcc, 0, false);
    dlg = new dialog();
}

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void DLLDestroy() {
    delete dlg;
    delete qApp;
}

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void setText(std::wstring str){
    dlg->setText(QString::fromWCharArray(str.c_str()));
}

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int add(int a, int b){
    return dlg->add(a, b);
}
```

The file structure seems correct (`qt_form` is my dll):

[image: The file structure seems correct:]

Comment: Why do you create an application object in the library?

Answer (score 0):

If the EXE is not in the same folder as the Qt libraries, have the EXE call [SetDllDirectory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setdlldirectoryw) with the path of the folder containing your DLL and Qt DLLs.

Or ammend the PATH environment variable to include this folder.